# Python extremely puzzling regex unicode behaviour

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-2.7

I use a tokenizer to split french sentences into words and had problems with words containing the french character `â`.

I tried to isolate the problem and it eventually boiled down to this simple fact:

```
>>> re.match(r"’", u'â', re.U)
>>> re.match(r"[’]", u'â', re.U)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x21d41d0>
```

`â` is matched by a pattern containing `’` **if** it's put in an ensemble matcher.

Is there something wrong on my part regarding UTF-8 handling or is it a bug?

My python version is:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
```

**EDIT**:

Hum, embarassingly enough, it seems that replacing the `r` prefixing the pattern with a `u` fixes the issue.

I wonder why the official documentation uses extensively `r` then `:((`

Comment: `r` is correct and important. You should **add** `u` (see the answer) instead of replacing `r`.

Comment: @m.buettner: yup I edited before seeing the answer. I went on and checked what `r` and `u` do, and indeed both are important. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pattern should be a unicode string too:

```
 >>> re.match(ur"’", u'â', re.U)
 >>> re.match(ur"[’]", u'â', re.U)
```

Otherwise apparently `sre` encodes `â` to latin-1 and finds the resulting byte in the three bytes that is a utf-8 `’`.

`"[’]"` is equivalent to `"[\xe2\x80\x99]"`, and `u'â'.encode('latin-1')` is `\xe2`.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I noticed it just before you answered :)

Comment: `re.U` does not magically turn on unicode, it just changes the meaning of `\w`.